# how to target a specific CSS3 background layer for modification in CSS and/or JS

Tags: javascript, css, background, background-image

As described here...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

... CSS3 supports a comma separated list syntax for layering multiple backgrounds on a single element. Their example css is this:

```
 background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11305/firefox.png),
      url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11307/bubbles.png),
      linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-repeat: no-repeat,
      no-repeat,
      no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right,
      left,
      right;
```

Let's say that I want to modify just one of these layers later, like through JS or using a `:hover` pseudo class. How would I be able to target just one of these layers.

For example suppose I want to move the firefox logo from the `bottom right` to the `top right` and I want to change the `bubbles.png` layer to be repeating.

How would I achieve this through CSS?

How about JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial way is to redefine the 3 values:

```css
.box {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11305/firefox.png),
      url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11307/bubbles.png),
      linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-repeat: no-repeat,
      no-repeat,
      no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right,
      left,
      right;
}
.box:hover {
background-repeat: repeat,
      no-repeat,
      no-repeat;
background-position: bottom right,
      bottom,
      right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Or you can use CSS variable to define the values you want and you can change them later without changing the others:

```css
.box {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11305/firefox.png),
      url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11307/bubbles.png),
      linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-repeat: var(--r,no-repeat),
      no-repeat,
      no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right,
      var(--p,left),
      right;
}
.box:hover {
   --r:repeat;
   --p:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can also do the same using JS:

```js
document.querySelector(".box").addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  e.target.style.setProperty('--r','repeat');
  e.target.style.setProperty('--p','right');
})
```

```css
.box {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
background-image: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11305/firefox.png),
      url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11307/bubbles.png),
      linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30, 75, 115, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  background-repeat: var(--r,no-repeat),
      no-repeat,
      no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right,
      var(--p,left),
      right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: I like your suggestion of css variables!